# javascript json iteration to get key and value

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to iterate the json below, I have got this as an output of an astify of sql parser. Now i want to validate the column type with a DB schema that i have.

```
{
  "with": null,
  "type": "select",
  "options": null,
  "distinct": null,
  "columns": "*",
  "from": [
    {
      "db": null,
      "table": "TABLE_1",
      "as": null
    }
  ],
  "where": {
    "type": "binary_expr",
    "operator": "AND",
    "left": {
      "type": "binary_expr",
      "operator": "AND",
      "left": {
        "type": "binary_expr",
        "operator": "=",
        "left": {
          "type": "column_ref",
          "table": null,
          "column": "COLUMN_1"
        },
        "right": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "NORM"
        }
      },
      "right": {
        "type": "binary_expr",
        "operator": "IN",
        "left": {
          "type": "column_ref",
          "table": null,
          "column": "COLUMN_2"
        },
        "right": {
          "type": "expr_list",
          "value": [
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "11"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "12"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "13"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "14"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "15"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "16"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "17"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "18"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "42"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "43"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "44"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "45"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "101"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "102"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "103"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "104"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "128"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "129"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "130"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "131"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "159"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "right": {
      "type": "binary_expr",
      "operator": "OR",
      "left": {
        "type": "binary_expr",
        "operator": "IS NOT",
        "left": {
          "type": "column_ref",
          "table": null,
          "column": "COLUMN_3"
        },
        "right": {
          "type": "null",
          "value": null
        }
      },
      "right": {
        "type": "binary_expr",
        "operator": "=",
        "left": {
          "type": "column_ref",
          "table": null,
          "column": "COLUMN_4"
        },
        "right": {
          "type": "number",
          "value": 1
        }
      },
      "parentheses": true
    }
  },
  "groupby": null,
  "having": null,
  "orderby": null,
  "limit": null
}
```

Can you please help me get an output like which will help me identify the column and its type whether its string or not. Basically i need to validate the query whether its mapped against the correct data type while using a var condition.

Output like:

```
map = <key,value>
<Column_1, String>
<Column_2, String>
<Column_3, INT>
etc.
```

Comment: In this json , I cannot see the column names. Do you need to traverse the complete json object or some specific keys?

Comment: "left": {
          "type": "column_ref",
          "table": null,
          "column": "COLUMN_1"
        }, theses are the column names.

Comment: I added the answer , it will return you an array of all the columns in your object. You can use typeof operator to find the type of the string. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Parse the JSON into an object using JSON.parse(), then iterate through them while checking if the value is JSON or not.

Check if the value is JSON by using catch on JSON.parse()

To get the object keys for iteration, Use var keys = Object.keys();

Answer (score 0):

@Suzy, please check below code for your reference:

```
var arr = {
  "with": null,
  "type": "select",
  "options": null,
  "distinct": null,
  "columns": "*",
  "from": [
    {
      "db": null,
      "table": "TABLE_1",
      "as": null
    }
  ],
  "where": {
    "type": "binary_expr",
    "operator": "AND",
    "left": {
      "type": "binary_expr",
      "operator": "AND",
      "left": {
        "type": "binary_expr",
        "operator": "=",
        "left": {
          "type": "column_ref",
          "table": null,
          "column": "COLUMN_1"
        },
        "right": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "NORM"
        }
      },
      "right": {
        "type": "binary_expr",
        "operator": "IN",
        "left": {
          "type": "column_ref",
          "table": null,
          "column": "COLUMN_2"
        },
        "right": {
          "type": "expr_list",
          "value": [
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "11"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "12"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "13"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "14"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "15"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "16"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "17"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "18"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "42"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "43"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "44"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "45"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "101"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "102"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "103"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "104"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "128"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "129"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "130"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "131"
            },
            {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "159"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "right": {
      "type": "binary_expr",
      "operator": "OR",
      "left": {
        "type": "binary_expr",
        "operator": "IS NOT",
        "left": {
          "type": "column_ref",
          "table": null,
          "column": "COLUMN_3"
        },
        "right": {
          "type": "null",
          "value": null
        }
      },
      "right": {
        "type": "binary_expr",
        "operator": "=",
        "left": {
          "type": "column_ref",
          "table": null,
          "column": "COLUMN_4"
        },
        "right": {
          "type": "number",
          "value": 1
        }
      },
      "parentheses": true
    }
  },
  "groupby": null,
  "having": null,
  "orderby": null,
  "limit": null
};

function findProp(obj, key, out) {
    var i,
        proto = Object.prototype,
        ts = proto.toString,
        hasOwn = proto.hasOwnProperty.bind(obj);

    if ('[object Array]' !== ts.call(out)) out = [];

    for (i in obj) {
        if (hasOwn(i)) {
            if (i === key) {
                out.push(obj[i]);
            } else if ('[object Array]' === ts.call(obj[i]) || '[object Object]' === ts.call(obj[i])) {
                findProp(obj[i], key, out);
            }
        }
    }

    return out;
}

console.log(findProp(arr, "column"));
```

Comment: The above is giving me only the column names . but i want the column names along with the datatype. "left": {
          "type": "column_ref",
          "table": null,
          "column": "COLUMN_1"
        },
        "right": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "NORM"
        }
      },

Comment: So i need as COLUMN_1, String